# Vectorized component wise multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Store 2N vectors of size d in two matrices `a` and `b` where `a.shape = b.shape = (N,d)` (so `a[i]` is the ith vector in `a`, which contains N vector, same with `b`).

I would like to construct in a vectorized manner the tensor `T` of shape `(N,d,d)` such that `T[i,p,q] = a[i,p]*b[i,q]`.

In other words, I would like to have a tensor which ith component is the (d by d)-matrix of component wise multiplication of the elements of `a[i]` and `b[i]`, without doing a for loop.

I tried using tensordot on multiple axes, or dot with no avail. Any idea?

Comment: Is `a[i]` the ith column or row vector?

Comment: Can you please post in a minimum working example some test data and the failed `tensordot` and `dot` operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `einsum` the calculation writes itself:

```
np.einsum('ip,iq->ipq', a,b)
```

That expression also makes it clear that there's no summation - just products. This is a kind of outer product, not an inner or matrix one.  In which case `tensordot` won't help.  But broadcasting should:

```
a[:,:,None] * b[:,None,:]
```

(Sometimes I have to reverse the order of the `None`. It helps to use `p` and `q` that are different to check that.)

You didn't provide a MCVE to check my answer against.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concise and clear answer